# Extract groupby value for a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a data frame with columns `Timestamp`, `Longitude`, `Latitude`. I have extracted the column `Distance` between each set of `longitude` and `latitude`. 
The problem statement of dataset is `extract the location between which the vehicle is at halt..` So concept i have used is, `if i+1 value is less than 500m` it is considered as `halt`. I want to extract the observation for the halt values.
**Example:** If it is halted, i want to extract the first longitude and lattitude and the last. Similarly for the timestamp. I have written the below code

```
df["Status"] = 'M'

for i in range(len(df)-1):
    if (df.loc[i+1,'Distance_km'] <= 0.5):
        df.loc[i+1, "Status"]='H'
```

Initially i created a column with values `M` for all. I changed it to `H` if the distance is less than 500m.

How to extract?

The dataframe snippet i have:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uGxt.png)

the output i want:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANpNF.png)

Comment: what do you mean by `if i+1 value is less than 500m` , is it next `Distance_km` value of the datframe minus current `Distance_km` value ?

Comment: how can i paste the values i have and expected output?

Comment: there is an `edit` option below the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume this is your dataframe (I filled it with random numbers for the most part):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lon': np.random.uniform(size=10), 'lat': np.random.uniform(size=10), 'time': np.arange(10), 'dist': [0,0,10,15,0.25,0,0,12,13,14]})

        lon       lat  time   dist
0  0.934316  0.577665     0   0.00
1  0.126991  0.665957     1   0.00
2  0.526884  0.590803     2  10.00
3  0.652709  0.873958     3  15.00
4  0.967095  0.320934     4   0.25
5  0.479600  0.012705     5   0.00
6  0.243327  0.117992     6   0.00
7  0.788706  0.193073     7  12.00
8  0.172656  0.166983     8  13.00
9  0.661242  0.030701     9  14.00
```

Using `pd.Series.where`, you can flag the halted rows. Ones in this column correspond to the vehicle being halted.

```
df['halted'] = df.dist.where(df.dist > 0.5, 1).where(df.dist <= 0.5, 0)

        lon       lat  time   dist  halted
0  0.934316  0.577665     0   0.00     1.0
1  0.126991  0.665957     1   0.00     1.0
2  0.526884  0.590803     2  10.00     0.0
3  0.652709  0.873958     3  15.00     0.0
4  0.967095  0.320934     4   0.25     1.0
5  0.479600  0.012705     5   0.00     1.0
6  0.243327  0.117992     6   0.00     1.0
7  0.788706  0.193073     7  12.00     0.0
8  0.172656  0.166983     8  13.00     0.0
9  0.661242  0.030701     9  14.00     0.0
```

Now for extracting your desired values. First, I'll introduce a column to identify the different halt groups

```
df['group'] = (np.abs(df.halted.diff()).cumsum().fillna(0) + 1) * df.halted

        lon       lat  time   dist  halted  group
0  0.934316  0.577665     0   0.00     1.0    1.0
1  0.126991  0.665957     1   0.00     1.0    1.0
2  0.526884  0.590803     2  10.00     0.0    0.0
3  0.652709  0.873958     3  15.00     0.0    0.0
4  0.967095  0.320934     4   0.25     1.0    3.0
5  0.479600  0.012705     5   0.00     1.0    3.0
6  0.243327  0.117992     6   0.00     1.0    3.0
7  0.788706  0.193073     7  12.00     0.0    0.0
8  0.172656  0.166983     8  13.00     0.0    0.0
9  0.661242  0.030701     9  14.00     0.0    0.0
```

Every halt group now is assigned it's integer greater than zero. With this, you can use `pd.DataFrame.groupby` to accumulate your values.

```
aggregated = df.groupby('group')['lon', 'lat', 'time'].agg(['first', 'last']).iloc[1:]

            lon                 lat            time     
          first      last     first      last first last
group                                                   
1.0    0.934316  0.126991  0.577665  0.665957     0    1
3.0    0.967095  0.243327  0.320934  0.117992     4    6
```

Lastly, calculate the time difference and drop unused columns:

```
aggregated['time_diff'] = aggregated.time['last'] - aggregated.time['first']
aggregated = aggregated.drop(columns=['time'])

            lon                 lat           time_diff
          first      last     first      last          
group                                                  
1.0    0.934316  0.126991  0.577665  0.665957         1
3.0    0.967095  0.243327  0.320934  0.117992         2
```

Using the `group` variable, you can join the results back to the other dataframe if you need the data back there

Comment: Thanks a lot :) This was what i was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this is what you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#generate random test data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({"Distance_km":np.random.random_integers(0,4,5), "Status": ["M"]*5})

print(df)
   Distance_km Status
0          4    M
1          0    M
2          2    M
3          3    M
4          2    M

# advance by one row and set the new status
df.loc[df["Distance_km"].shift(-1) < 0.5, "Status"] = "H"

print(df)
   Distance_km  Status
0           4   H
1           0   M
2           2   M
3           3   M
4           2   M
```

**Edit**

If you want to have these pairs, for which "H" has been set:

First get the indices:

```
idx = set(df[df"[Status"]=='H'].index) &  set(df[df["Status"].shift(-1)=='H'].index)
```

Than extract the row pairs:

```
for i in idx:
    print (df.loc[i:i+1]) #note: this is python3.x syntax for print, for 2.x remove ()
```

Comment: yes i have done this already. I have added an snippet of output i required. So basically what i need is i want the locations details between which vehicle is at halt :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to mark moving or halt

```
import numpy as np
print(df)
    Latitude    Longitude   Time_diff   Distance_km Speed
0   22.63138    72.90793    0           0.000000    0.000000
1   29.45170    76.96690    54          60.114052   66.793391
2   29.45170    76.96690    59          0.000000    0.000000
3   29.45170    76.96690    59          0.000000    0.000000
4   29.84198    76.91140    52          43.699876   50.422934
5   30.83144    75.98629    59          1.482713    1.507844
6   30.83547    75.98839    59          0.490619    0.498935
7   30.83547    75.98839    59          0.000000    0.000000
8   30.83547    75.98839    59          0.000000    0.000000

df['Status'] = np.where(df.Distance_km.shift(-1)>=0.5,'M','H')
df = df.assign(Latitude_1=df.Latitude.shift(-1),Longitude_1 =df.Longitude.shift(-1))
print(df[df.Status =='M'])

    Latitude    Longitude   Time_diff   Distance_km    Speed      Status    Latitude_1  Longitude_1
0   22.63138    72.90793    0           0.000000       0.000000    M        29.45170    76.96690
3   29.45170    76.96690    59          0.000000       0.000000    M        29.84198    76.91140
4   29.84198    76.91140    52          43.699876      50.422934   M        30.83144    75.98629
```

Comment: here what i want is, if Status=='H', i want lat1 as latitude at which the status started as 'H' and lat2 as latitude at which it was last 'H'... In general, i want location between which the vehicle was at halt and total time for which it is at halt. I hope i am clear :)